# Impersonation using Selenium

Tags: .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, impersonation

I am developing the windows application using Selenium inorder to test a website.

As per one of the requirement I used impersonating concept of the .net and then I tried to launch the IE webdriver as shown below

```
// Please assume I set the IEDriver.exe to the correct path
IwebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(IEDriver.exe path which is in my local machine);
```

then I am facing the error

`Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Could not get document from window handle(NoSuchDriver)`

Any help is appreciated.....

Comment: give us the Selenium version you are using, and the iedriver version you are using.

Comment: Am using 2.39.0 version of selinium and 2.39.0 version IEdriver

Answer (score 0):

You don't need IEDriver.exe, but instead IEDriverServer.exe, and you should be able to get the application from [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list).
Once you have IEDriverServer.exe in your project you should be able to create a new ieDriver like this:

```
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"FilepathToButNotIncludingIEDriverServer.exe");
```